# Chrome not Firefox are not dumping to SSLKEYLOGFILE variable

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, encryption, wireshark

I'm trying to decrypt SSL packages with Wireshark as described [here](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/). I have already created a SSLKEYLOGFILE System and User variable and the log file. I have restarted my computer (running Windows 10), and opened https urls with Chrome and Firefox, but none write to the ssl log file. My Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) and my Firefox version is 51.0.1 (32-bit). Any idea how can I make any of the two browsers write to that file? Or is there any way to get the SSL key to be able to decrypt SSL packages in Wireshark?

Answer (score 16):

You are doing something wrong. Tested on version 58 & you do not need to reboot. To activate either:

1. set environment variable e.g. `SSLKEYLOGFILE` to `%USERPROFILE%\sslkeysENV.pms`
2. run chrome with argument e.g.:
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ssl-key-log-file=%USERPROFILE%\sslkeysARG.pms`

Comment: The syntax for this answer was originally incorrect but I have submitted an edit that fixes it (your path was off slightly and you need a double dash -- for the flag). With that said I had some success off my vpn, but on VPN within corp. network, it seems to work sometimes and others not. not sure what the difference is.

Comment: As of 9/27/2019, Chrome stable (standard, macOS) doesn't work with option 1. I didn't test option 2. However, [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) works with both options 1 and 2.

Comment: Option 2 works in Mac OS: "open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app  --args --ssl-key-log-file=<some_file>"

Comment: how to run chromium with arguments https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

Comment: For me, the problem with #1 was **how** I was setting the environment variable. My everyday user account doesn't have local administrative permissions, as per best practice, but a side effect is that I couldn't use System Properties as it elevates to the context of my administrative user account, so I had no choice but to use Command Prompt / PowerShell. For some reason, `set SSLKEYLOGFILE=<path to file>` doesn't work (Process Monitor shows no attempts to interact with the path), but `setx SSLKEYLOGFILE "<path to file>"` does, even though the output of `set` for both is identical.

Answer (score 5):

With Firefox the features seems to be disabled by default and is [only available in debug builds](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1183318). With Chrome this might have been vanished by switching the underlying SSL engine from NSS (which implemented this feature and is also used in Firefox) to BoringSSL (which maybe does not have this feature).

Update: according to @Lekensteyn (see comment) the feature is again available in current Firefox and Chrome builds.

Comment: Firefox has only disabled the key logging feature in one release, they reverted that and the current version does support the feature. Chrome does support this feature with BoringSSL as well.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Thanks for this up-to-date information. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it!

You **MUST** be sure chrome totally be closed. And then reopen a fresh new chrome instance.

Chrome has a default options **let chrome run in background** enabled.

Double check your taskbar of windows or processes lists to make sure **there's no chrome instance exists.**

That's why `--ssl-key-log-file` don't working, chrome stills alive after you click exit button.

Answer (score 2):

Try Firefox Developer edition, the above mentioned feature is turned on by default. I tested yesterday only.

Answer (score 2):

Some antiviruses (like Avast) inject the SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable into well-known processes like firefox.exe and chrome.exe. If you rename the browser executable file and launch that, then the environment variable won't be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close your current browsing session, it behave like you just add a new path to PATH, only work from the new session and so on.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score -6):

Besides what they have already pointed out, I want to show three points that may help. These are tips for Linux (CentOS)

1. Make sure the file that related to `SSLKEYLOGFILE` can be written and read, to make sure you can use:

   ```
   chmod -R 777 sslkey.txt
   ```
2. Make sure your Firefox or Chrome is opened under the same user with the file mentioned, for example under root.
3. Find some useful comments [here](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/)

Comment: 1. `chmod 640 sslkey.txt` would be preferable. Other/anyone shouldn't have permissions to SSLKEYLOGFILE; you could instead chgrp to a common user group or setfacl if the filesystem supports access control lists. 2. You should not run a browser as root. 3. `setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/sbin/dumpcap; chmod o-rx /usr/sbin/dumpcap` avoids granting root permissions to the packet capture utility (which should probably, TBH, be run as a user without read permissions to the current user's files).