# Chrome is not logging SSL KEY in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, wireshark

I'm trying to decrypt HTTPS using Wireshark on Ubuntu 20.04.

I use [this](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/) guide.

Basically:

1. You install Wireshark
2. You add `SSLKEYLOGFILE` environment variable
3. You open Chrome and visit the HTTPS site
4. You import the ssl key log file into Wireshark
5. And it decrypts the traffic

But no matter what I do, my `.ssl-key.log` file is empty. I closed Chrome and reopened it. Visited https://google.com and nothing is written in that file. I even restarted my laptop.

And these questions did not solve my problem:

[Chrome not Firefox are not dumping to SSLKEYLOGFILE variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332792/chrome-not-firefox-are-not-dumping-to-sslkeylogfile-variable)

[SSLKEYLOGFILE environment variable doesn't populate any text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498386/sslkeylogfile-environment-variable-doesnt-populate-any-text-file)

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports it anymore. I know firefox does (ver 97), so use firefox.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, then how can one decrypt HTTPS in Wireshark without Firefox?

Comment: But you said Chrome does not support it anymore.

Comment: My bad, I misread your question. You cannot decrypt HTTPS when using chrome, period. At least, I cannot find anything that says how to do it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk should we believe someone who died in 1849?

Comment: @C0ntr07: I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I use chrome(Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)) is worked.

you should run `killall chrome` to kill all chrome background instance.
then rerun google-chrome is work.

OR

user fiddler decrypt HTTPS，

https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps

Decrypt HTTPS traffic with Wireshark and Fiddler

https://www.hhutzler.de/blog/decrypt-https-traffic-wireshark-fiddler/

Comment: I actually restarted my laptop alltogether. That is more than killing Chrome. My version is 98.

Comment: I use Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) for tested.it's worked. PS:Need in terminal run `google-chrome` ,not click chrome icon for run..

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that Google Chrome doesn't have access to your user environment.

To resolve this,

- launch `google-chrome` directly from a user terminal whenever you want to decrypt new traffic
- or make a psueo-google-chrome launcher that points to the real google-chrome after setting the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` env variable